# Try Except: как обработать два одинаковых исключения подряд?

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, beautiful-soup, try-catch

Пишу парсер для сайта, где на разных страницах в одном и том же месте блоки имеют разное название. Пытаюсь это обойти при помощи `try - except`, но в результате все равно получаю ошибку: `AttributeError: 'NoneType'`.

Подскажите, как обработать два одинаковых исключения подряд?

```
try:
    # Попробуй тэг "gray db"
    db_count = tr.find('td', class_='gray db').text.strip()
    print(db_count)
except AttributeError:
    # Если нет "gray db", попробуй "gray db rowspan"
    db_count = tr.find('td', class_='gray db rowspan').text.strip()
    print(db_count)
except AttributeError:
    # Если нет и "gray db rowspan", то запиши "неогранич."
    db_count = 'неогранич.'
    print(db_count)
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

```
tr.find('td', class_='gray db')
```

найдет все атрибуты **td** с классами и **gray db**, и **gray db rowspan**

Дело не в except, скорее всего, а в динамически подгружаемых данных на странице.

Но если нужно найти разные class_ , то два раза

```
except AttributeError
```

не отработает, работа завершиться после после первого же исключения.
Вы можете использовать вложение исключений, например:

```
db_count = ''

try:
    # Попробуй найти тэг "gray db"
    db_count = tr.find('td', class_='gray db').text.strip()
except AttributeError:
    try:
        # Если нет "gray db", попробуй "rowspan"
        db_count = tr.find('td', class_='rowspan').text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        # Если нет и "rowspan", то запиши "неогранич."
        db_count = 'неогранич.'
   
print(db_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

если требуется обработать что-то такое однотипное, и проверок достаточно много, то удобнее в цикле сделать

```
for c in ['gray db', 'gray db rowspan', '...', , '...', '...', '...']:
    try:
        db_count = tr.find('td', class_=c).text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    db_count = 'неогранич.'
```